# How to activate This Class to another

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, accelerometer, core-motion

I have a question about using another class in my main GameplayScene. What I am trying to do is make the motions of the X-axis of the phone move the character left and right. Here is what I have in my MotionClass.swift

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

class MotionClass: SKScene {

    var player: Player?

    var motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    var destX: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func sceneDidLoad() {

            motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.2
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
                if let myData = data {

                    let currentX = self.player?.position.x

                    if myData.acceleration.x > 0.2 {
                        self.destX = currentX! + CGFloat(myData.acceleration.x * 100)
                        print("Tilted Right")

                    } else {

                    if myData.acceleration.x < -0.2 {
                        self.destX = currentX! + CGFloat(myData.acceleration.x * 100)
                        print("Tilted Left")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

        let action = SKAction.moveTo(x: destX, duration: 1)
        self.player?.run(action)
    }

}
```

Now I'm trying to call this class in my GameplayScene.swift in the motionBegan function, but I don't know how to go about doing that. I have the variable 'grapple' as MotionClass? but I don't know where to go from there. Could anyone give a good an example on doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confused about the purpose of an `SKScene` subclass, which is what your MotionClass currently is. (The main idea) is to only use one SKScene at a time: if you need stuff from MotionClass then you should just make it a plain class, not an `SKScene` subclass.

I think you may also need to familiarize yourself a bit more with OOP as well... Outside of `static` properties / functions, you don't "call" a class, you *instantiate* it ( you make an object :] )

So, if you have goodies in MotionClass that you want to access in GamePlayClass, you need *a reference to a MotionClass object*

This can be done with a simple global variable... I suggest putting it into your GameViewController.swift:

```
// Here is a global reference to an 'empty' motion class object..
var global_motionClassObject = MotionClass()

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // ...
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? else {
      let scene = MotionClass(size: view.frame.size)
      // Assign our global to the new scene just made:
      global_motionClassObject = scene
      scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

      view.presentScene(scene)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now inside of your GamePlayClass, or wherever else, you can access MotionClass by calling `global_motionClassObject`

However, this may not give the desired results because I'm worried you may need to restructure your MotionClass into something other than an SKScene :)

Comment: I already have the let scene = GameplayScene, I should change it?

Comment: In that case no.. if you aren't `.presentScene` for motionclass, then you can just instantiate it _inside_ of your GamePlayScene... No global necessary unless you are swapping back and forth between scenes

Comment: I'm just wanting to know how to implement it to my GameplayScene after the initial var motionManager: MotionClass?

Comment: @DarinWilson implement what? I'm really confused now :P Why don't you just put motionManager in your gameplayscene, and configure it there? You can't put an SKScene inside of SKScene.. I mean.. at least not the way you are thinking.

Comment: So I need to make its class MotionClass {} then rework all my overrides? Or forget my MotionClass and just put all the code in my GameplayScene? Sorry I'm confusing you. I'm just trying to learn XD

Comment: @DarinWilson its cool. let me take a step back. MotionClass, as it is now, does nothing except move your player on touch. All of your CoreMotion stuff is done with that instance of motionManager, which you can put anywhere. the stuff configuring motionmanager can be put anywhere. What reason does MotionClass exist for outside of the above? if nothing, scrap it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143520/discussion-between-darin-wilson-and-fluidity).